# Geopandas plot is streched

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, geopandas

I'm trying to plot a state of Germany with geopandas. Unfortunately the plot is a bit streched.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gpd

shapes = gpd.read_file('shapes.shp')
shapes.plot(figsize=(20,20), color='white', edgecolor='black')
```

If I execute the code above, I'll receive the following plot.
[image]
But if you compare the shape of the plot to the real shape of the state as displayed below, then this plot is a bit streched.
[image]

I tried to adjust the axes and the figsize, but I didn't work.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you show the code you tried adjusting?

Comment: I use different functions e.g. `plt.axis(...)`. I cannot reproduce them all.

Comment: Also what happens if you remove the `figsize` argument? I assume this is just a problem with aspect ratio

Comment: It is the same plot but smaller. So the shape stays the same.

Comment: Your drawing is not projected. The distance between the horizontal ticks should be (cosine of 49 degrees×2)  approximately 1.72 times the distance between your vertical ticks, but the horizontal distance is exactly 2 times the vertical one: you have not used a map projection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As gboffi mentioned the projection is not right. So i changed it to EPSG:3857.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gpd

shapes = gpd.read_file('shapes.shp').to_crs(epsg=3857)
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(15,15))
shapes.plot(ax=axs, color='white', edgecolor='black')
```

[image]